# Datasource subrow empty after filter cleared

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-table

I have a material table with expandable rows. In this expanded row I have another table with the same columns as the 'main' table.
I also have some filters, those filters are in a form, so when the value changes I can filter the dataSource.

When I initialize the page I fetch the data for the table, and store the result in a global variable.

In the same OnItit I subscribe to the valueChanges event of the form.
And this is the part where I have some problems. I declare a variable based on the `allData` variable. In the datasource I have subRows and wheb I try to filter on this sub array it also changes the data in the `allData` variable. When I filter on the first level of the datasource it is no problem.

```js
public allData;
public dataSource;

public ngOnInit(): void {
   this.allData = this.service.getData(someProperties);
   this.filterForm.valueChanges.subscribe((filters) => {
      this.filterDataSource(filters);
   });
}

public filterDataSource(filters) {
   const filterdData = this.allData;
   // apply filters on main level works fine
   // In this case this.allData does not change
   filterdData = filterdData.filter((x) => {
      return x.property.includes(filters.search);
   });

   // sublevel does not work
   // In this case this.allData does change
   // The subRow in this.allData will be empty after the search is cleared when the
   // filter did not find anything when the filter was applied
   for(let index = 0; index < filterData.length; index++) {
      filterdData[index].subRows = filterdData[index].subRows.filter((x) => {
         x.property.includes(filters.search);
      });
   }
   

   this.dataSource.data = filterdData;
}
```

The result of a search action and the removal of the search is the folowing:

```js
// before filter
allData = [
   {
      property: 'present', 
      subRow: [{
         property: 'im here'
      }]
   },
   {
      // and so on
   }

]

// after filter cleared
allData = [
   {
      property: 'present', 
      subrow: []
   },
   {
      // and so on
   }
]
```

Comment: What's our filters.search value ? By the way I think you can't write, `const a = b; a = c;`

Comment: @nubinub ```filters.search``` is a string and comes from a input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform a deep copy of allData.
The easiest way is probably to use [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).

```
let filteredData = cloneDeep(this.allData);
// Apply your filter the way you did
```

If for some reason you can't use lodash, you need to perform those copy "by hand". Assuming your data model is always the same as the one you posted:

```
const filteredData =  this.allData.filter((x) => {
  return x.property.includes(filters.search);
}).map((data) => ({...data}));
// Worth noting that this solution does not perform a deep copy, but should be enough with the way you are filtering your data.
```

To go deeper in object references undestanding:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Shallow_copy
- https://medium.com/dev-proto/simple-explanation-of-objects-and-memory-references-in-javascript-1b2310c36c31